# Sharepoint 2010 - Bloqueio e Desbloqueio de Campos de Lista com Javascript

Tags: sharepoint

Bom dia!

Estou com um problema numa lista do Sharepoint 2010. Fizemos um código Javascript aqui no trabalho que faz com que analistas tenham dois campos, bloqueados para edição de usuário, desbloqueados. O problema é que todos os membros do grupo de analistas estão caindo no bloqueio de usuário.

```
<script src="/-/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/-/js/spjs-utility.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/-/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/strategy/sp/js/jquery.SPServices-2014.01.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().SPServices({ 
        operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
        userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
        async: false,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            if (($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='nomedogrupo']").length == 1)) {
                campos que devem ser bloqueados para analistas
            }
            else{
                campos que devem ser bloqueados para usuários
            } 
        } 
    });
</script>
```

O que poderia estar causando o problema? Já verifiquei e estamos todos incluídos no grupo corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente seu código está correto. Cheque o nome do grupo se realmente está batendo com o que está cadastrado no Sharepoint.

Se quiser tentar de outra forma segue uma solução sem utilizar o SPServices:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(VerificarPermissoes, "SP.ClientContext");       
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', VerificarPermissoes);
});

function VerificarPermissoes() {
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
    var currentUser = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();    
    clientContext.load(currentUser);
    var userGroups = currentUser.get_groups();  
    clientContext.load(userGroups); 
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(OnQuerySucceeded);

    function OnQuerySucceeded() {  
        var ehAnalista = false; 
        var groupsEnumerator = userGroups.getEnumerator();          

        while (groupsEnumerator.moveNext()) {   
            var group = groupsEnumerator.get_current().get_title(); 

            if(group == "Nome do Grupo Analistas"){ 
                ehAnalista = true;
            }
        }   

        if(ehAnalista){
            //campos que devem ser bloqueados para analistas
        }
        else{
            //campos que devem ser bloqueados para usuários
        }       
    }   
}
```